# why the bleu score is zero for this pair even though they are similar

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, bleu

why I'm getting 0 score even though sentences are similar. Please refer the code below

```
from nltk.translate.bleu_score import sentence_bleu

score = sentence_bleu(['where', 'are', 'economic', 'networks'], ['where', 'are', 'the', 'economic', 'network'])

print(score)
```

score value is '0' if u run the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with how you hand the references to the method.

Check out the [documentation](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/translate/bleu_score.html) or more specifically [this sample of how to use it](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/translate/bleu_score.py#L28).

References have to be a list (a list of all reference translations to compare the hypothesis with). So in your case a list containing the one tokenized reference translation.

Use it like this and it will work:

```
score = sentence_bleu([['where', 'are', 'economic', 'networks']], ['where', 'are', 'the', 'economic', 'network'])
> 9.283142785759642e-155
```

Although I have to admit I have struggled with the exact same problem before and this is not very intuitive on NLTKs part. The documentation even states that references has to be of type `list(list(str))` but then doesn't check if this is the case and instead returns a misleading result when used incorrectly.